# Testing a desktop application using test manager

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Is it feasible to test a desktop application using test manager? if yes, what are the limitations in doing so, if any?

Comment: You should provide more information about the tests you want to run.

Comment: @Elena : i want to perform an automated data driven test, in which i will be providing an external source (excel sheet), import it in the application and then needed to verify the data in the database, whether it is imported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is it feasible to test a desktop application using test manager?*

Yes, basically that what's *Test Manager* is for (along with manual testing).

> *if yes, what are the limitations in doing so, if any?*

Well... that depends on tests you want to implement.
Importing data from an excel sheet to database and verify whether it is imported after that is a quite simple test. You should be able to run it without any problems.

I would highly recommend you this **free** e-book: [Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35380)
If you are using Visual Studio 2010 this book will be helpful, too, since the approach is similar.